# Вопрос по grunt. Возникающие ошибки

Tags: grunt

Осваиваю **grunt**. Вот это пишу в грантфайл:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Вся настройка
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        dist: {
            src: [
                'js/libs/*.js', 
                'js/common.js'  
            ],
            dest: 'js/build/production.js',
        }
    }

    imagemin: {
        dynamic: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'images/',
                src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'images/build/'
            }]
        }
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

// задачи
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'imagemin']);
```

};`

Первая задача проходит нормально. Со второй ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, что за идентификатор он ожидает и почему не находит дефолт? Пробовала разбить команды по файлам - ничего не дало. Надеюсь кто-нибудь сможет объяснить в чем проблема и что я делаю не так?

Comment: А можете показать package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас пропущена запятая на 17 строчке, должно быть так:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Вся настройка
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        dist: {
            src: [
                'js/libs/*.js', 
                'js/common.js'  
            ],
            dest: 'js/build/production.js'
        }
    },

    imagemin: {
        dynamic: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'images/',
                src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'images/build/'
            }]
        }
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

// задачи
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'imagemin']);

};
```

package.json

```
{ 
    "name": "blogPete", 
    "version": "0.1.0", 
    "devDependencies": { 
        "grunt": "~0.4.1", 
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.0", 
        "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0", 
        "grunt-csso": "^0.8.1" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: А нет, все получилось. Такая банальная ошибка( Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

У вас не хватает запятой после описания модуля concat.

Напишите так:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Вся настройка
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'js/libs/*.js', 
                    'js/common.js'  
                ],
                dest: 'js/build/production.js',
            }
        },

        imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'images/',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: 'images/build/'
                }]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

    // задачи
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'imagemin']);
};
```

Comment: вставила запятую, результат тот же. В package.json '{
  "name": "blogPete",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-csso": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
'